# design approach for loading data from different sources (Oracle, flat files) using Java

Tags: java

I am looking around for a design approach on loading data from different sources (oracle, flat files etc) and loading them in the target relational model using Java. I already have the target data model in place, currently it has four entities a,b,c,d - where d has references of a,b,c ids, so I need to populate the first three tables. 
for entity a:
I need to read a record from source and compare it with already existing in entity a (In first load it will be empty so I would directly insert it), compare on all the columns of that record, if there is difference then I would update the target else I move to other record.
I am considering Spring batch, but for comparing each and every record I will have lot of DB calls which would impact the performance.
I would appreciate help on designing strategies. I don't want to consider ETL tools like informatica, abinitio etc.

target database would always remain as Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest way to do this is to load all the records into a temporary table on the target. Then you can run a Minus query (if your target is Oracle) between the 2 tables to find all records that need to be inserted, all others to be updated.